# Media queries orientation: landscape not working

Tags: css

Media queries orientation: landscape not working

i have done a long search, and have found many others with this same issue

i tried suggested code, still my landscape media queries will not work

they will not show the correct orientation: landscape media queries

my portrait code is exactly the way i want it

some of the posts may have been dated, by years, so i hope to get a fresh set of eyes and new blood into this repetitive head ache

i think that orientation: landscape would be straightforward.. insert the code i want and move on...

am i an idiot and missing some thing obvious?

please help me to make my orientation: landscape code work.. avoid JS if you can

MANY THANKS!!

---

yes, some code would be a good idea!

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 812px){
     #banner h1 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }

    
  }@media screen and (max-width: 812px){
      #banner {
height: 12rem;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 812px){
    .mySlides .text{
font-size: 1rem;
    }
  }
```

please see [www.forallthetime.com](http://www.forallthetime.com) on  smart phone...

you will see its awful

i am trying to code orientation: landscape for the home page and navigation throughout

bring the landscape to the way i want it

i thought it simple, but my simple code doesn't work

i know it maybe a bit sloppy, work in progress...

also, i regret the way i coded this... my foundation should have been better!

lesson learned there!

any other help is appreciated

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried so far? :-) 
Welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code provided i am not entirely sure where your problem is.

When i try using a media query with orientation:

```css
.landscape-test {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
  .landscape-test {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="landscape-test"><div>
```

you will need to show code in a full page to test it.